# A product of bounded and null sequences is a null sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Assume $\{x_k\}$ and $\{y_k\}$ are two sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}x_k = 0$ and $\{y_k\}$ is bounded. prove $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (x_k \centerdot y_k) = 0$

I'm honestly not even sure where to start with this, so we have two convergent sequences but I don't know how to prove the dot product converges to 0 as well

Comment: Try to use $|x_k\cdot y_k|\leq|x_k|\cdot|y_k|$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$\forall \epsilon>0\quad \exists M\quad \forall n>M\quad |x_n|<\epsilon$$also $|y_n|<B$ for some $B>0$ therefore$$|x_ny_n|\le |x_n|\cdot |y_n|<B|x_n|<B\epsilon$$for $n>M$. Therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_ny_n=0$$